# Is it possible to develop web-based games using Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, web, corona-sdk, webapp

Some clients asked me to develop 2D web-based games and later on they might want to release those games on mobile platforms.

I know Corona and I don't want to rewrite my code twice. Is it possible to create web-based games using Corona (the free SDK)?

Comment: Take a look at Haxe and OpenFL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Corona is beta testing Corona Cards. It will support embedding Corona in a Html document. (AKA Corona on web!)

Check out their site for more: 
http://coronacards.com/

Comment: How much I costs? I see it's free trial but can't navigate easily on my phone

Comment: CoronaCards isn't available yet. It is currently in its beta state, and will be available to the public soon. You can apply for the closed beta at their site: http://coronacards.com/

Comment: The pricing just came out today: http://coronacards.com/pricing/

Answer (score 2):

No, Corona does not build for web platforms.